# "He gave me the sharpness to penetrate for truths, but not the braveness to face them."

Tags: ellipsis, parallelism

> He gave me the sharpness to penetrate for truths, but not the braveness to face them.

or should it be

> He gave me the sharpness to penetrate for truths, but didn't give me the braveness to take them.

Comment: The first one sounds better to me for some reason.

Comment: _Braveness_ is not a word; it's _bravery_ or, better still,  _courage_.

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically valid (leaving aside the issue of the word "braveness", which is not a standard dictionary form) and their meaning is the same. I think the first sentence, omitting the repeated verb give/gave, is better and stronger writing.